# imprimir tabla con inputs usando DataTables plug-in

Tags: php, datatables

alguien sabe cómo se pueden imprimir los valores de los input que estén dentro de la tabla, ya que como [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) te permite exportar tu tabla HTML a PDF, EXCEL y más , los campos estáticos o fijos los trae bien pero si en uno de eso campos uso un input no me toma el valor del input al momento de imprimir, así tengo mi código:

esta es mi tabla dinamica:

```
foreach ($totales as $code){

echo "<tr>";
    
echo "<td>" . $code["codigo"] . "</td>";
    
echo "<td>" . $code["descripcion"] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $code["cantidad"] . "</td>";

echo "<td> <input type='text'><span style='display: none;'></span> </td>";
    
echo "</tr> ";

}
```

y esto es lo que se usa para imprimir la tabla :

```
        $(".example1").DataTable({


            dom: 'Bfrtip',

            buttons: [

                {

                    extend: 'excelHtml5',

                    exportOptions: {

                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]

                    }

                },

                {

                    extend: 'csvHtml5',

                    exportOptions: {

                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]

                    }

                },

                {

                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',

                    title: 'Expense Report',

                    filename: 'expense_report',



                    exportOptions: {

                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]

                    }

                },

            ]

        });
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes formatear usando la función [body](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html), desde ahí consultas si un elemento es `input`, si lo es retornas su valor, caso contrario asumimos que es texto y se retorna aquel texto

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            let exportOptions = {
                format: {
                    body: function (valor, row, col, node) {
                        if ($(node).children("input").length > 0) {
                            return $(node).children("input").first().val();
                        } else {
                            return valor;
                        }
                    }
                },
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
            };
            $('.example1').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        exportOptions: exportOptions
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        exportOptions: exportOptions

                    },
                    {

                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        title: 'Expense Report',
                        filename: 'expense_report',
                        exportOptions: exportOptions
                    },

                ]

            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/datatables.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <table class="example1 display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Otra cosa</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>desc1</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="231" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>55555</td>
                <td>desc4</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="555" /></td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar una función aparte para revisar si el nodo tiene un `input` o no, en caso de que tenga algún `input` entonces obtener su valor, de lo contrario regresar `data`.

Ya que no se han incluído los datos, tomé una tabla de [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html) para hacer un ejemplo genérico que tendrás que adaptar con tus datos y tus botones, solo implementé `print`.

**Nota:** El sitio no permite `pop ups` así que te dejo una liga a un [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57n1aqhe/) donde puedes verificar su funcionamiento.

```js
// Función para revisar si el nodo exportado contiene input
var getInputValue = {
    exportOptions: {
        format: {
            body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                    // Revisar si el nodo tiene input, si es así, regresa el valor
                // del input, en caso contrario regresa "data"
                return node.firstChild.tagName === "INPUT" ?
                        node.firstElementChild.value :
                        data;
            }
        }
    }
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
                $.extend( true, {}, getInputValue, {
                extend: 'print'
            }),
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td><input type='text'></td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td><input type='text'></td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td><input type='text'></td>
                <td>2009-06-25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td><input type='text'></td>
                <td>2011-12-12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```